# Access multiple rows in a form using a search box

Tags: forms, ms-access, search

I hava a form which I search data in a table. It has a textbox to input the data. I want to search for and a button do the search.
It has the design below:

```
[search box][Search Button]  
[         text box        ] <-- this field shows the data I've insert in search box and search using the Search Button
```

I've nailed it using macros, it works perfectly, but it only show the first data, not all.

`e.g:   [Ann  ][SB]`

```
[Anna Alfred]
```

I type "Ann" and the press the search Button [SB] and in the text box it appear "Anna Alfred".

But I have more than one Anna! I have Anna ALfred, Anna Portland, Anna Smith, ...

My doubt is: can I show multiple items in this form?

`E.g:   [Ann   ][SB]`

```
[Anna Alfred  ]

[Anna Portland]

[Anna Smith   ]`
```

When I'm not searching, I need it to show all the items in a table with all the names in the table,
when I'm searching I need it to show all the items that contains the data I'd input in the searchbox.

Comment: Your post probably doesn't have enough information to allow a precise answer.  I suggest you just follow the instructions at http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-03.html or (more complicated) http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-32.html.

Comment: Nevermind, i found out a way. just did the form as multiple itens. Ty

Comment: Good!  I think you should make that a 1-sentence answer and then Accept the answer.  Alternatively, delete the question (heh heh, you may get a badge for that).